# Jquery contains is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need only jquery solutions, I have a span `<span style="font-weight: bold;">`Text goes her like this, why this contains is not working in jquery, it will alert all span including bold, please help

```
$('#contentarea').bind('click',function(e){
                if($(e.target).is('span')){
                    if($(e.target).find('span:contains("italic")')){
                        alert('italic');
                    }
                }
        });
```

Comment: read the doc, :contains is for content not attribute

Comment: ok that is fine, but i am getting the same error, yesterday i asked the same question but the replied answers are not satisfying my need, if you knows that please feel free give me a possible solution, i am new in jquery

Answer (score 1):

[:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) looks for the elements containing the specified text, not the css properties

You need to

```
$('#contentarea').bind('click',function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is('span')){
        if($target.css('font-style') == 'italic'){
            alert('italic');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: did you mean font-style?

Comment: @pebbo sorry copy paster mistake